# What do you call illegal or unaccounted money in politics?

Tags: word-request

Suppose, there's a legally allowed limit which a person seeking election can spend on his campaign. Money receivers and donors are disclosed, a legal campaign account has its limitations so a politician uses unaccounted money which can exceed legally reported expenditures by several times. In Russian, there's a phrase that can be literally translated as "a black cash register" (or, less literally, "black funds"). In English, can I say 'under-the-counter cash'? If not, how can I say otherwise?

Comment: unreported campaign contributions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the expression [**off-the-books**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/off%20the%20books):

> : not reported or recorded
>   // *off-the-books* transactions
>   // *off-the-books* covert operations

It applies to more than just money, but it certainly does apply there too.

For instance, you could say:

> Their campaign was financed by *off-the-books* contributions.

Comment: "Off-the-books transactions" are illegal, aren't they?

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev They certainly can be, although they don't have to be. But you had asked for something illegal or unaccounted. *Off-the-books* things are at least unaccounted for, and generally (but not necessarily) illegal by connotation

Answer (score 1):

In Indian English we use "**Black Money**" for money which is kept off the official books and on tax is intended to be evaded.

Specifically to your question, "**Slush Funds**" is a term that denotes a hidden or unaccounted sum of money that is kept aside for bribery or other illicit activities.

It has been used to refer to unaccounted funds used in election campaigns, as well as corporate funds reserved for bribes and lobbying where the source of funds is visible but destination is obscured.

For example;

> [Choi] used her friendship with the South Korean leader to pressure
> businesses into donating to charitable foundations, which served as
> her personal slush fund.
>
> -- [Spiritualist at Centre of Crisis Goes on Trial; The Nelson Mail (New Zealand); Dec 20, 2016](http://wordsmith.org/words/slush_fund.html).

"Slush Funds" has an interesting etymology, it is claimed to originate in the navy around 1830's from "[the fat or grease (slush) skimmed from the top of the cauldron when boiling salted meat.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slush_fund)" The income thus earned from selling this unaccounted fat from a ship's galley would create an unofficial fund for small luxury expenses.

Answer (score 0):

“Dark money” is the closest equivalent I can think of in English, American English in particular. However, in the United States, “dark money” is not necessarily illegal, it just implies that the source of the money is unknown (and would most likely want to remain unknown).

Not a perfect match, but I can’t think of anything closer to what you are looking for.

“Under-the-counter” tends to suggest more that you are avoiding taxes, and is not usually used to describe political donations.

Comment: I read a bit of the Wiki page on the term and got the impression that it refers to legal money: undisclosed but lawfully so. It's not what I'm looking for

Comment: I agree, but as I say I’m not sure there’s anything in English exactly equivalent to that Russian phrase. Newspapers etc. might simply say “illegal donations” or something similar.

Comment: Is 'under-the-counter cash' really bad?

Comment: “Under-the-counter” is used more in cases where someone wants to avoid taxes. If you employ someone and pay them in cash, and don’t declare it for tax purposes, you might say you are “paying them under the counter”. But this phrase is rarely, if ever, used to describe political donations, illegal or otherwise.

Comment: the term is **unreported campaign contributions**: money used in campaigns is called contributions. The money must be reported to the IRS, etc.

Comment: @Lambie It's not even a term. It's what I'm looking a term for

Comment: @mat_noshi Can I use words like 'off-[something]' or 'out-of-[something]'? You know, for example, the adjective 'off-the-record'. Such words mean beyond the bounds of something or not being part of something. Can I use or construct a similar word for my purpose? 'Off-the-account' or something to that effect, I hope you got the idea

Comment: “Off the books” is a common phrase, but again it is used more in the sense of tax evasion by a business. Part of the problem, in the United States at least, is that there are few limits on political donations and contributions, and so they are usually legal.

Comment: under-the-counter transactions, but not under-the-counter cash.